# Grunt task to modify javascript file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have following node.js javascript file.

```
module.exports = function(){
    ...
    var config1 = "";
    var config2 = "";
    var config3 = "";
    ...
}
```

Suppose I have following grunt task.

```
grunt.registerTask('task1', ['...',copy]);
grunt.registerTask('task2', ['...',copy]);
grunt.registerTask('task3', ['...',copy]);
```

Depending on which task I am running, config1, config2, config3 varible value should change.

For example:

```
grunt task1
```

should produce

```
module.exports = function(){
    ...
    var config1 = "A";
    var config2 = "B";
    var config3 = "C";
    ...
}
```

while 
    grunt task2

should produce

```
module.exports = function(){
    ...
    var config1 = "X";
    var config2 = "Y";
    var config3 = "Z";
    ...
}
```

Is there any grunt plugin which can do this or similar?

Comment: So you basically want to alter raw Javascript files? If there was a grunt module out there, how should this possibly look like? That there are placeholders where your values should be? That would ultimatively result into syntactically incorrect Javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple stuff like this, I just use grunt-replace.  Give it a regex to find each line and a string to replace that line with what you want the output to be.  This doesn't actually parse your code though so if you later do some refactoring, the regex's will need to change.